# How can I resolve an error "Incorrect syntax near 'unpivot'." in a stored procedure I am trying to create?

Tags: sql-server

The environment is MS SQL Server 2008-R2. Compatibility Level is at 80.

I have a set of data that tracks scrap in a manufacturing operation. It has  columns along the lines of this. There are many more columns for reasons for a part to be scrapped, but this is representative.

```
Site  WorkCenter  CloseDate  Scratches  Chips  Broken  Supplier
----  -----------  --------  ---------  -----  ------  --------
OH    PGL1         4/2/2018          1      4       2         0
MI    E350         4/2/2018          0      1       9         2
OH    FF11         4/3/2018          8      1      14         0
```

and so on.

I have created a select that unpivots this data.

```
SELECT 
    Site,
    WorkCenter, 
    CloseDate, 
    Reason,
    U.Loss
FROM 
    #tmp 
unpivot ( loss FOR Reason IN ([Scratches], [Chips], [Broken], [Supplier]))     as U
```

It runs without issues or errors.

```
Site WorkCenter  CloseDate  Reason       Loss
---- ----------- ---------- ------------ ----------- 
MI   CGR1        2018-04-02 Broken       3
MI   CGR2        2018-04-02 Broken       6         
MI   CIM         2018-04-02 Broken       5
```

This unpivot expresses the scrap reason columns as rows to facilitate some further analysis.

The problem arises when I put this select statement in a stored procedure.
Here is the stored procedure. The first part does some aggregation of the underlyng sql data into a temp table. The select from the temp table does the unpivot.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spUnpivotRejectData 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FromDate datetime, 
    @ThruDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT 
    Site, 
    [Work Center] as WorkCenter, 
    cast(cast(wo.CLOSE_DATE as date) as datetime) as CloseDate,
    sum([Scratches]) as Scratches, 
    sum([Chips]) as Chips,
    sum([Broken]) as Broken, 
    sum([Supplier]) as Supplier
into
    #tmp
FROM 
    VMFG.dbo.VW_PTG_REJECT_CODES rc
left outer join
    VMFG.dbo.WORK_ORDER wo on
    wo.BASE_ID = rc.[WO Num]
WHERE (cast(cast(CLOSE_DATE as date) as datetime) Between @FromDate And     @ThruDate)
group by
    Site, 
    [Work Center], 
    cast(cast(wo.CLOSE_DATE as date) as datetime)

SELECT 
    Site,
    WorkCenter, 
    CloseDate, 
    Reason,
    ASMT.Loss
FROM 
    #tmp t
unpivot( loss for Reason IN ([Scratches], [Chips], [Broken], [Supplier]))     as  
        ASMT
drop table #tmp

END
GO
```

I cannot create the stored procedure as I get this error:

```
Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spUnpivotRejectData, Line 60
Incorrect syntax near 'unpivot'. You may need to set the compatibility     level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See     help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.
```

I am stumped given the fact that the select runs standalone but will not work as part of a stored procedure.

Anybody out there have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: The error is literally telling you what to do here. Use a higher compatibility level; or don't use `UNPIVOT`, which was introduced in SQL Server 2008. Compatibility level 80 is SQL Server 2000, why are you using such an old (and unsupported) version?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This client is not actually using SQL 2000. The version, as stated in the post, is 2008 R2. I am hesitant to make that change on the client's SQL instance as it backs an ERP system which I do not manage. What prompted the post was really the "why does the select work but the stored procedure throws this error?" I can pursue the possibility of changing the compatibility mode.

Comment: @Long answers that below. And the reason it probably works is that the latter statement is run against a table in TempDB, and I imagine you weren't connected the the older compatible DB. In the SP, the context will all be run in the old compatibility level.

Comment: perhaps you migrated the old databases from an older version to the later version and did not change the `Compatibility level`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it is due to:

> When PIVOT and UNPIVOT are used against databases that are upgraded to
>   SQL Server 2005 or later, the compatibility level of the database must
>   be set to 90 or higher.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105)

What you can do is right click on the database that you are running the query on, go to `Options`, set the `Compatibility level` to 90 or above (Installed SQL Server version matters)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I have asked the client to contact the ERP system vendor's support group to ensure that a change in compatibility level on their database won't cause any issues.